# How to place symbols on top of each other (not \overset, \underset)?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I tried to set two symbols on top of each other via:

```
\begin{align*}
  \Rightarrow\atop\nLeftarrow
\end{align*}
```

How can I reduce the space between the symbols? `\overset` etc. is what I normally use, but that reduces the size of one of the symbols and I would like them to be of the same size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `\genfrac` command from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{\Rightarrow}{\Leftarrow}
\]
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is to use an array environment. In this case an optional argument to the `\\` macro allows you to manually adjust the vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle\Rightarrow \\[-5pt]
\displaystyle\Leftarrow
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```