# like \rightleftarrows from amssymb, but with hook and twohead, respectively

Tags: symbols, arrows, stacking-symbols

I would like to have a symbol that looks like the symbol \rightleftarrows from amssymb, but I want the morphism to the right to be a twoheadrightarrow and the morphism to the left to be a hookleftarrow. Can you help me?

Comment: Could you draw a picture for exaction? I think, there are several options for this.

Comment: Please have a look into the comprehensive symbol list: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf, with a lot of arrow symbols, perhaps the one you look for is listed there.

Comment: Thank you. Meanwhile, I also found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65017/how-to-place-symbols-on-top-of-each-other-not-overset-underset, which seems to be a good solution.

Comment: \newcommand\retraction{\ensuremath{\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle\twoheadrightarrow\\[-7pt]
\displaystyle\hookleftarrow\end{array}}} scheint das gewünschte zu leisten. Allerdings würde ich das Pfeilpaar gerne in einer Überschrift verwenden, bekomme aber bisher lauter Fehlermeldungen. Hat jemand einen Tipp?

Comment: @RooibosTee: Nicht alle sprechen hier Deutsch ;-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why `\begin{array}...\end{array}`???

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot that I have to write in English. The command "\newcommand\retraction{\ensuremath{\begin{array}{c} \displaystyle\twoheadrightarrow\[-7pt] \displaystyle\hookleftarrow\end{array}}}" does what I want, but I'm having trouble to use it inside a \section{ }.

Comment: @Christian Das hab ich von dort: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65017/how-to-place-symbols-on-top-of-each-other-not-overset-underset.

Comment: @RooibosTee: Ok,but we have no idea what you want to achieve: Please post an image in your question.

Comment: The `\section` trouble is cured by `\protect` in front of `\retraction`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrowheads of `\twoheadrightarrow` are quite different from the arrowhead of `\hookleftarrow`; here's a solution that makes up a two head right arrow from two `\rightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\retraction@inner}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      ##\cr
      $\m@th#1\hookleftarrow$\cr
      \makebox[\widthof{$\m@th#1\hookleftarrow$}][s]{%
        $\m@th#1\mkern-.5mu\to\hss\to\mkern-.5mu$%
      }\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\retraction}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\retraction@inner\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$A\retraction B_{\retraction}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This even works within a \section{...}, which is fine, even though I'm not exactly sure why it does...

Comment: @RooibosTee `\DeclareRobustCommand` is the key.

Comment: @egreg -- much nicer than mine.  but does it matter here to the meaning which is above and which below?  (i've always assumed that it usually does.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've never cared; in this case the hook arrow is best placed above because of the relative shapes.

Answer (score 3):

here's my attempt, using a technique stolen from the `\substack` command in `amsmath`.

the arrow without the tail is a bit shorter than the other, since the tail is simply
added onto tn existing arrow (and they're all the same length), so i've used the minus
sign (as traditional with computer modern) to extend it a bit.

this version will scale to the current size, since it might appear in a footnote
(smaller), or possibly a heading (larger), with the use of `ex` (vertical) and
`mu` (horizontal) units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\retraction
 {\ensuremath{\mathrel{\subarray{c}
  \mkern.7mu{-}\mkern-12mu\twoheadrightarrow\\[-.55ex]
  \hookleftarrow\endsubarray}}}

\begin{document}

\[
A \retraction B
\]

\Large
\[
A \retraction B
\]

\small
\[
A \retraction B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Argument braces are missing for `\ensuremath`. In text mode only token `\mathrel` is put into math mode.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek -- right.  thanks.  (i never use `\ensuremath`, but i should really know better what the syntax should be.)  fixed.